# Use variable within arrays and use its property as variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I really want to take variables from array index to its own array index property. now here's my code so far, but it didn't work. Hopefully this would visuallize you to what I mean.

```
const CHARACTERS: Character[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'hei', image: './c' + this.id + '/' + 'portrait.png'},
  { id: 2, name: 'ok', image: './c' + this.id + '/' + 'portrait.png'},
  { id: 3, name: 'whatever', image: './c' + this.id + '/' + 'portrait.png'}
]
```

I want the `image` property resulting value to

```
./c1/portrait.png
./c2/portrait.png
./c3/portrait.png
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function e.g

```
const createCharacter = ({id, name}) => ({ id, name, image: './c' + id + '/' + 'portrait.png'})

const CHARACTERS: Character[] = [
  createCharacter({id: 1, name: 'hei'}),
  createCharacter({id: 2, name: 'ok'}),
  ... 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const NAMES: {id: number, name: string}[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'hei'}
  { id: 2, name: 'ok'}
  { id: 3, name: 'whatever'}
]

const CHARACTERS: Character[] = NAMES.map(item, ({id,name}) => {
  return {id, name, image: './c' + id + '/' + 'portrait.png'
});
```

Comment: what version of angular did you using?
I got errors

Comment: I fixed the problem